# How to insert multiple check-box values to a same column of a SQL Database using C#? This should be done by a button click

Tags: c#

private void btn_Add_Tourist_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

//How to insert multiple check-box values to a same column of a SQL Database using C#? This should be done by a button click
        {

```
      SqlConnection AddTourist = new SqlConnection("Data Source=VDESHANE;Initial Catalog=GreenwayTravelsLankaDB;Integrated Security=True");
       {
           SqlCommand Insert_TouristData = new SqlCommand
                ("Insert into Tourist_Details (First_Name, Last_Name, Country, Email, Number_Of_Pax, Adults, Children, Date_Of_Arrival, Date_Of_Departure, Meal_Plan, Celebrating, Category, Requests) Values (@First_Name, @Last_Name, @Country, @Email, @Number_Of_Pax, @Adults, @Children, @Date_Of_Arrival, @Date_Of_Departure, @Meal_Plan, @Celebrating, @Category, @Requests)", AddTourist);


            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", txt_First_Name.Text);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", txt_Last_Name.Text);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", txt_Country.Text);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txt_Email.Text);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number_Of_Pax", txt_Pax.Text);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Adults", txt_Adults.Text);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Children", txt_Children.Text);

            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Of_Arrival", date_Arrival.Value);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date_Of_Departure", date_Departure.Value);



            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Meal_Plan", Meal_Plan_list.Text);
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Celebrating", Celebrating_list.Text);
```

// All the othe functions works fine... but the checkbox issue remains the problem
                // <-------------NOT WORKING CORRECTLY

```
           while (check_Cultural_Site.Checked)
            {
            Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Cultural Site,");

                while (check_Boat_Trips.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Boat Trips,");
                }

                while (check_Cycling.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Cycling,");
                }

                while (check_Trekking.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Trekking,");
                }

                while (check_Nature.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Nature,");
                }

                while (check_Bird_Watching.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Bird Watching,");
                }

                while (check_Rafting.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Rafting,");
                }

                while (check_Beach_Vacation.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Beach Vacation,");
                }

                while (check_Wild_Life.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Wild Life,");
                }

                while (check_Camping.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Camping,");
                }

                while (check_Shopping.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Shopping,");
                }

                while (check_Dolphin.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Dolphin,");
                }

                while (check_Diving.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Diving,");
                }

                while (check_Whale_Watching.Checked)
                {
                    Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", "Whale Watching,");
                }

           }

  //NOT WORKING CORRECTLY ---------------->



           Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Requests", txt_Requests.Text);

            AddTourist.Open();
            Insert_TouristData.ExecuteNonQuery();
            AddTourist.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("DATA SUCCESSFULLY ADDED");


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks really ugly: use linq or some other ORM that provides parametric queries.

Comment: you're replacing the value of `@Category` every time you are calling `AddWidthValue()`. What is the destination column type?

Comment: Please explain. Do you want to set the column Requests with something like `Diving,Shopping,Camping`? What is the datatype and the size of the column Requests in the datatable `Tourist_Details`?

Comment: @Steve you got it right (Y) data type is varchar(1000)

Comment: hey i'm new to programming soo please help out guys.....I could not add any image cause i have less reputation point in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` to create a string with all the Interests checked separated by a comma, then store this string as a whole in the column Requests

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if(check_Cultural_Site.Checked)
   sb.Append("Cultural Site,");
if(check_Boat_Trips.Checked)
   sb.Append("Boat Trips,");
..... and so on ....
... and at the end of the list of if .....

// Remove the last comma
if(sb.Length > 0)
   sb.Length--;

// Just add the parameter one time and assign the value of the StringBuilder to it
Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", sb.ToString());
```

You should check that if someone ticks everything the list doesn't exceed the 1000 chars allowed by the datatable field and, for a better readability of the method, I suggest to move this long list of ifs to a separate function.

```
string interests = GetInterests();
Insert_TouristData.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Category", interests);
```